# How to load website HTML using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I load some website in my java-script so that I can parse it?
I want to get Html of e.g. www.google.com and I want to select all the  tags in it using jquery.

Comment: You can't do this in Javascript because of the AJAX same-origin policy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't as jquery doesn't allow you to load external resources, unless in the page you want to parse is present the header:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://thesitewhereyourjscodeishosted');
```

If you can't set it, you could use PHP:

```
<script>
var website = <?php echo file_get_contents("http://websitetoload"); ?>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Due to browser security restrictions, Ajax requests are subjected to the same origin policy; the request can not be successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, port, or protocol.

But you can build a script on your server that requests that content or can use a proxy, then use `jQuery` `ajax` to hit the script on your server.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/fDN7t/)**

It's just proxying a request through Yahoo's servers and getting back a `JSONP` response even if the requested server doesn't support `JSONP`.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="example"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#example').load('http://wikipedia.org');
```

Here is a similar question like yours [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily set up node server that gets the content of the page, and then make an ajax request to your server and get whatever data you need.