# How to show web page nested in div?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have simple HTML code,

```
<div id="overlay">
        <div>
            <p>Content you want the user to see goes here.</p>
            Click here to [<a href='#' onclick='overlay()'>close</a>]
         <div>
             <object type="text/html" data="http://google.com"></object>
         </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I get error as,

> This content cannot be displayed in a frame

How to show webpage inside div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and other sites use a [X-Frame-Options HTTP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) that specifies that embedding is only allowed from the same origin:

```
x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
```

Browsers respect this header and prevent you from embedding the site

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`<iframe>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) to show page inside page

```
<iframe src="http://example.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: `google` is restrict load content inside `<iframe>` due to `CORS` policy try another site

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is, that Google is sending an `"X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN"` response header. This option prevents the browser from displaying iFrames that are not hosted on the same domain as the parent page.

**[The X-Frame-Options response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)**

Here is work around;

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eukx5e7j/)**

```
<iframe id="if1" width="100%" height="254" style="visibility:visible" src="http://www.google.com/custom?q=&btnG=Search"></iframe>
```

Here is an other workaround to overcome your problem;

[**How to load website HTML using jquery?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26184630/how-to-load-website-html-using-jquery/26191541#26191541)

good luck!